# Open the folder on the cursor with another application NerdTree

Tags: vim, filesystems, nerdtree

I'm using NERDTree, it would be awesome if, when I'm with the cursor over a folder, I had a way to call my file manager, say thunar, whit a mapping to open that folder. Like Sublime does.

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar like this on windows. This executes a command on the current directory (when doing `:pwd` in vim).

I do not know how to directly do this in Nerdtree but it is a start. Do keep in mind if you press `cd` on a folder in Nerdtree the working directory automatically changes to the folder you are on so it is fairly quick.

Add following to your vimrc.

```
" Open current file in New Google Chrome window
command Chrome :silent ! start chrome /new-window "%:p"
" Open current file in Windows explorer
command Explorer :silent ! start explorer "%:p:h"
```

Explanation:

- command Chrome => you can execute the command in vim by pressing :Chrome
- :silent => open the window without having to confirm in vim
- ! => this is where the command line command starts
- %:p:h => the current working directory, literally this means the path (:p) of current file (%), without the head (:h).

In your case it will be something like:

```
command Thunar :silent ! thunar "%:p"
```